# Next page by selecting radio buttons not with clicking next page

Tags: jquery, ajax, drupal, radio-button, drupal-webform

what i want is this when i click on the radio buttons it takes me to the next page without me actually clicking on the next page.
At the moment i have to click on *next page*

Application form link: **http://goo.gl/CNgJq**

I have written this code but it doesn't seem to work:

```
(function ($, Drupal, window, document, undefined) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.form-radio').click(function() {
            $('.next-tab mover').click();
        });
    });
})(jQuery, Drupal, this, this.document);
```

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0):

Test case: http://jsbin.com/acopuj/1/edit

```
$('.next-tab mover') // <---- that's wrong
```

should be:

```
$('.next-tab.mover') // the button has both classes, add '.' and remove 'space'
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your page, you need to change your selector to `$('.next-tab.mover')`. This will find the element with both the `next-tab` and `mover` classes.

```
$('.form-radio').click(function() { $('.next-tab.mover').click(); });
```

Comment: It's not... I didn't get a notification that there was already an answer as I was typing mine

Answer (score 0):

You could try this one

```
$('.form-radio').on('click', function() {
    $('.next-tab.mover').trigger('click);
});
```